How to detect powershell commandlets that need administrator?
Assuming I have a powershell function to run a command and log the output to file that other scripts are also logging to, is there a generic way to detect that a PowerShell commandlet has not executed to completion because it requires Administrator privileges?
For example, running Initialize-Tpm as a regular user outputs "Administrator privilege is required to execute this command", but sets the $LASTEXITCODE to 0, sets the status $? to True, and doesn't add any errors to $Error. So other than explicitly checking the commandlet output for that string, how can I tell it didn't work?
I can't find a way to get such commandlets to indicate an error when they stop, and using Get-Command on initialize-Tpm doesn't indicate RequiresElevation either.
Do I just need to maintain my own list of commandlets that I know need admin?
(I don't want to explicitly check for Administrator privileges at the start of the encompassing powershell script for other reasons.)

Exit codes are for processes, not cmdlets. What's the value of $? after Initialize-Tpm returns

@MathiasR.Jessen After Initialize-Tpm then $? == True regardless of whether it ran as desired or if it just output the "admin is required" message.

Are you sure you can maintain a list of cmdlets that require an "administrator"? Where would you put Remove-Item? It all depends on the resource you try to read or modify, not on the tool.

@stackprotector of course I'm not sure. :( but I can't find any other way to identify such commands, as shown above.
